# How to Compress Image but not resize it Using Xamarin IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to upload an image to server which is pretty large around, But i want to keep the Aspect Ratio but compress the size of the file because I am uploading multiple files.

Comment: In the question you say keep the aspect ratio, but in the title you say not resize. Are you willing to resize the image to have a smaller width and height while maintaining aspect ratio? You can get some compression by sending a JPG or PNG representation with `UIImage.AsJPEG()` or `UIImage.AsPNG()` without resizing. Resizing to a smaller image can save even more space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to resize your image, then sending it as JPEG and PNG will make it smaller than just sending the bitmap data. You can get `NSData` representation of the image in PNG or JPEG. There are some pros/cons to each format, but JPEG allows sacrificing quality for more compression.

*Assuming you have a `UIImage` named `image`.

```
using(NSData pngImage = image.AsPNG()){
    byte[] imageBytes = pngImage.ToArray();
    // upload your image data, write to a file, etc.
}

// AsJPEG compression argument can be 0 to 1
// 0 is max compression (lowest quality), 1 is best quality
using(NSData jpgImage = image.AsJPEG(0.0f)){
    byte[] imageBytes = jpgImage.ToArray();
    // upload your image data, write to a file, etc.
}
```

You can also use `AsJPEG` in a loop with decreasing values of compression to try and get the image size below a specific threshold. That might be a little slow though, so you have to weight the benefits for your specific use.

Comment: @VibhaRKedilaya Glad I could help. Happy developing.

Comment: Do you have any idea of implementing the same in Xamarin Android?

Comment: [Bitmap Compress](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Compress/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap+CompressFormat/System.Int32/System.IO.Stream/) should do the trick. The format parameter will be 0-100 instead of 0-1. You can use a `MemoryStream` as the stream, and ready it back into a `byte[]`.